# How to rename a file on sdcard with Android application?

Tags: android, runtime, filenames, rename

In my Android application, I want to rename the file name at runtime. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
String[] command = {" mv", "sun moon.jpg"," sun_moon,jpg"};
try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I also used renameTo(File f) method but it does not work.

Comment: Visit [this one][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065514/move-rename-file-in-sd-card

Comment: You need to accept answers if you want people to help you, FYI

Answer (score 89):

I would recommend using [`File.renameTo()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) rather than running the `mv` command, since I'm fairly sure the latter isn't supported..

Have you given your [application permission to write to the SD Card](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/security/security.html#manifest)?

You do this by [adding the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it doesn't work once the permission is added check the device log for errors when you try to rename the file (either using the `adb` command or in the *logcat* view in Eclipse).

When accessing the SD Card you shouldn't hard-code the path but instead use [the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) method to get the directory.

The following code works for me:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

and if you want to check the process, you can do like:

```
boolean renamed = from.renameTo(to);

if (renamed) {
  Log.d("LOG","File renamed...");
}else {
  Log.d("LOG","File not renamed...");
}
```

Comment: Now I try

 File f1=new File("/sdcard/sun moon.jpg");
       File f2=new File("/sdcard/soon_moon.jpg");
       try {
      f1.renameTo(f2);
     } catch (Exception e) 
             {
  Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

and use the permission
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 in androidManifest.xml file 

but still, there is no changes.

Comment: I've updated my answer with code that works for me.  Does `renameTo()` return `true` or `false` when you run it?  If it returns `false`, what does `f1.exists()` return?

Answer (score 5):

you can also explicitly give the full path without specifying directory...

```
File file = new File("Path of file which you want to rename");
File file2 = new File("new name for the file");
    boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding permissions. Even though it did not work, adding `File1.setWritable(true);` enabled me to rename the file.

Below is my code snippet:

```
if(from.setWritable(true))
    Log.d("InsertFragmentTwo ", "FileName==> Is Writable");
File two = new File(sdcard,""+imageCount+"."+s.substring((s.lastIndexOf(".")+1)));
if (from.renameTo(two)) {
    Log.d("InsertFragmentTwo ", "New FileName==> " + temp);
    imageCount++;
    retrofitImageUpload(temp);
} else
    Log.d("InsertFragmentTwo ", "File Renaming Failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectFile() {
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {
            "Select file from internal storage"};
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}
public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if(dir.exists()){
                File from = new File(dir, String.valueOf(GALLERY));
                File to = new File(dir,"filerename.txt");
                if(from.exists())
                    from.renameTo(to);
            }
        }
    }
}
```