# Move/Rename file in SD Card

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-sdcard

I'm trying to move a file from one directory to another (in SD Card)

I have a file's URI and the way I'm trying to move it:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData(); // this the uri, something like content://media/external/images/media/635

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard, selectedImage);
File to = new File(sdcard, "myNewDir/mynewfile.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

But it doesnt work, neither does it give me any error in Logcat...

**Edit:**

I have added both permissions to my manifest file:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what exactly happens?  Also, have you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: I updated my question a little bit. I have added permissions... nothing happens, it doesnt simply move the file and neither does it give me any errors about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// this the uri, something like content://media/external/images/media/635
```

What you are then doing is trying to concatenate this onto `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. This will not work. `content://media/external/images/media/635` is neither a relative filesystem path nor an absolute filesystem path. It is a `Uri`.

If you wish to copy the image from the `Uri` to a local file, use a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the image represented by the `Uri`, then use Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to your target file.

Comment: You are correct. I changed uri to absolute path and everything worked as needed.