# How do I rename a file when I'm uploading it with Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code working:

```
      MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
      entity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(f));
      httppost.setEntity(entity);
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The problem is that the name of the `File f` is "abc-temp.jpg" and I want it to be "xyz.jpg" when I upload it. I don't want to rename the file on the device though, **only** for uploading.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: if you upload it on server what about rename it on server by using web serivecs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application

Comment: @mohammed momn - At this point let's assume that's not possible for me to do.

Comment: @EthanAllen: it is possible,I have done it in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It is surely possible, In fact I have done it.

```
                    FileBody mFileBody = new FileBody(f);
                    String mUploadFileName = "xyz.jpg";

                FormBodyPart mFormBodyPart = new FormBodyPart("userfile", mFileBody)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void generateContentDisp(ContentBody body) {
                        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                        buffer.append("form-data; name=\"");
                        buffer.append("userfile");
                        buffer.append("\"");
                        buffer.append("; filename=\""+mUploadFileName+"\"");
                        addField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, buffer.toString());
                    }
                };
                multipartContent.addPart(mFormBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it will work, but you can create a class which will inherit from FileBody and will override getFilename() method.

I think it should do the trick.