# How to do Rename/Delete operations on audio files which are in SD card

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to delete and rename audio files which are in Sd card so here is my code to display list of audio files from SD card.

```
// Use the current directory as title
    path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (file.contains(".3gp")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
    // Put the data into the list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

here i am able to display all music files but if i tried rename or delete operations then it is not effecting to files which are in SD card ,suggest me some solution plz
CODE TO DELETE AND RENAME

```
case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:

Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "You selected item " + context_menu_number
                        + " from the context menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "You removed item " + number_of_item_in_listview
                        + " from the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        values.remove(number_of_item_in_listview);
        // myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //if this does not work,
        // reinitialize the adapter:
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                values);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        File f = new File(path + filename);
        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
            // delete it
            f.delete();
        }
        return (true);
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application

Comment: Where is your code to rename/delete file ?

Comment: Have you added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: yes,added permissions to manifest

Comment: do you want the code for deleting the file or you are facing some problems in the code you implemented?

Comment: Okay understood that i am deleting list item only not SD card content ,i want to delete file from SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to delete file from sdcard.

```
File file = new File(FilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

where `FilePath` is the path of the file you want to delete - for example:

```
/sdcard/YourCustomDirectory/YourFile.mp3
```

Also give the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Added permissions in manifest,Tried this code but it didn't work

Comment: Where have you written your code to select the file and get its path ?

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to write on external storage first in xml..

```
   String newName ="new Name";
   File oldFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+songName);

   File latestname = new File(Enviornment.get+ newName + ".mp3");
   boolean  success = oldFile .renameTo(latestname );
```