# How to make the app automatically rename a folder

Tags: android, decompiling, smali

I have an app... I want to add a feature to that app. Feature is automatically rename a folder in sdcard.

It doing this. Download a file. Then it extract to sd card automatically. So is there anyway to make it rename automatically? Any code for smali?

Comment: You should mention that you only have the *binaries* of an app, i.e. the `.apk` file, and you want to rename a folder that app creates automatically. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Yes. I have the decompiled apk... Smali files and other xml files...  I want to rename that extracted folder... The folder is /sdcard/Android/data-test

Comment: You'll probably find the literal "data-test" somewhere in the decompiled resources. Once located, you can try and change that constant, re-compile the app, and see if that does the trick. - You may be infringing on copyright and/or license terms though!

Comment: In my app automatically deleting the data folder. Cannot find it on the app codes. Then I made the file extract as data-test folder. So I wanna do after extract rename data-test to data folder...

Comment: Can you make a little app to rename a specific folder? So when app launch the folder will rename automatically...

Comment: That should be really easy to do. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application.

Comment: I got the source code... Can u help me to get this rename method add to this source code of app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just use this code oldfilename.renameTo(new_file_name);

Comment: sorry please provide more info

Comment: I have the apk file... It doing a progress... All automatically... Downloading a file and then extracting that zip file... So I want to rename that extracted folder...

Comment: do you have the path of downloaded file

Comment: Path is /sdcard/Android/data-test

Comment: ha to just do this File oldpath = new("/sdcard/Android/data-test");

File newpath = new ("..."); // your new path

and at last oldpath.renameTo(newpath);

Comment: Can you make a little app to rename a specific folder? So when app launch the folder will rename automatically...

Comment: I got the source code... Can u help me to get this rename method add to this source code of app?

Comment: @NishanthaIndikaBandara plz write the code over here and i will change and give you