# Open Default File Manager and rename file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

I want to programatically launch a default file manager to show me the contents of a folder and I want delete or rename a file.

When I  run android app.It show content of folder only, but cannot rename file.

how can i do it?

I'm using this code.

```
openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("file/*");
  startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: did you add permission for write the file manager check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to programatically launch a default file manager

There is no "default file manager" on many Android devices. There is no requirement that any file manager respond to any particular `Intent` structure from third-party apps, other than `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` for the launcher icon. And there is no requirement that any app allow the user to rename anything from an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity.

You will need to implement your desired functionality yourself, perhaps with the assistance of [one of these libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).